# How to choose the previous closest value in sql

Tags: mysql, sql

Right now I have 2 tables:

*Table1 -*

**Date                Exchange Rate**

00/00/0000      0.6

4/1/2018          0.81

**4/2/2018       0.82**

5/1/2018          0.83

5/2/2018          0.81

5/3/2018          0.82

*Table2 -*

**Date                   USD**

2/2/2018            50

3/5/2018            60

4/1/2018            50

4/3/2018            100

4/15/2018          200

5/1/2018            60

5/2/2018            80

5/3/2018            90

I want to have a Table 3 that reflects the Converted Amount *Table3 -*

**Date                   USD        Converted Amount**

2/2/2018            50          50*0.6 = 30

3/5/2018            60          60*0.6 = 36

4/1/2018            50          50*0.81 = 40.5

4/3/2018            100        100*0.82 = 82

4/15/2018          200        200*0.82 = 164

5/1/2018            60          60*0.83 = 49.8

5/2/2018            80          80*0.81 = 64.8

5/3/2018            90          90*0.82 = 73.8

How would I make this happen in SQL? The original data is very big.

The thing is that I would like Table3's 4/15/2018 and 4/3/2018 converted_amount to follow the 4/2/2018 exchange rate, as there are no 4/15/2018 or 4/3/2018 exchange rate in Table1. Essentially I would like to have the missing exchange rate to follow their closest previous date's exchange rate.

Also, for all the dates prior to 4/1/2018, the exchange rate should follow Table1's 00/00/0000 exchange rate.

Really appreciate your help! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

You could use a correlated subquery which finds the closest date in table 1 for each date in table 2:

```
SELECT
    t2.Date,
    t2.USD,
    t2.USD * (SELECT t1.ExchangeRate FROM Table1 t1
              WHERE t1.Date <= t2.Date
              ORDER BY DATEDIFF(t2.Date, t1.Date) LIMIT 1) AS ConvertedAmount
FROM Table2 t2;
```

[image]

### Demo

Note this is something of an uncontrolled approach, because there could be two nearest dates in table 1 on either side of a date in table 2, and one might be chosen arbitrarily.  Really, a better long term approach here would be to use a calendar table which just has forex rates for every day.

Comment: Hi Tim, really appreciate your help. I just edited my question again, can you take a look? and plus, what does this part mean "ORDER BY ABS(DATEDIFF(t1.Date, t2.Date)) LIMIT 1" ? Thank you so much!

Comment: @Evie I made a change such that the prior rate gets used should it be missing for a date in table 2.

Comment: @Strawberry I'm back on a cell phone now, it's not so easy to see these edge cases.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen . . . It would be easier to update your answer if the question were formatted more readably.

Comment: Thank you so much @TimBiegeleisen this is really helpful